# No llegan los datos a una hoja de googlesheets

Tags: appinventor

tengo un problema con la app que estoy haciendo, resulta que necesito mandar esta info a una hoja de googlesheets
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden observar la primera línea es el formulario a donde debe llevar la info, es más la app me dice que llego bien la info, pero cuando reviso el libro no está registrado los datos, estos son los bloques que uso para enviar la info
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La verdad ya he buscado en todo sitio, pero sigue pasando lo mismo, de esta manera llega la info a la hoja:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La información que se ve en la imagen fue porque ingrese la dir que le paso a los bloques y me doy cuenta de que si funciona, pero cuando lo hago por la app no la envía, agradecería mucho la ayuda prestada